# Получение id через модальное окно

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте! Есть таблица, где значение `id` берется из бд:

```
<td>
    <?= $row['id']; ?>
</td>
```

Так же в таблице есть колонка с кнопками(для каждой записи своя кнопка):

```
 <td style="text-align: right">
                <button type="button" id="<?= $row['id'];?>" class="openModal btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" >Написать письмо</button>
  </td>
```

Кнопка открывает модальное окно.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
   ....
        <div class="modal-body" >
            <textarea class="mail"></textarea>
        </div>
    ....
            <button type="button" class="sendMail btn btn-primary">Отправить письмо</button>
        </div>
    </div>
     ....
```

Проблема в том что когда нажимаю на кнопку `Отправить` не могу получить id куда отправлять. У меня получается что модальное окно никак не связано с `id`.

Comment: @Alexander Igorevich, когда открываю я еще могу получить `id`, но вот когда отправляю уже никак. Попробовал сделать так: `        $('.openModal').on('click', function(){
             $("#myModal").modal('show');
        $('.sendMail').on('click', function(){ 
            var mail = $('.mail').val();

        });
     });` Т.е. засунуть один клик во внутрь другого, работает, только каждый раз получает свое значение и значение предыдущего клика

Comment: Обновил ответ. Например можно передавать полученный `id` в `data-атрибут` кнопки отправки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я понял это bootstrap. Уберите атрибуты `data-toggle="modal"` и `data-target="#myModal"`, так как вам требуется не просто открыть модальное окно, а ещё вытащить `id`.

На `.openModal` повесьте обработчик, который и будет открывать модальное окно (`$("#myModal").modal('show');`).

Там же, в обработчике, можно вытаскивать `id` и делать с ним что угодно. Например поместим полученный `id` в data-атрибут кнопки отправки, а при отправке будем его от туда брать.

```
$(document).on('click', '.openModal', function(e) { 
    var id = $(this).attr('id'); // получаем id кнопки, на которую нажали

    $("#myModal .sendMail").data('id', id); 
    // Теперь у кнопки "отправки" в data-атрибуте будет полученный id

    $("#myModal").modal('show'); // открываем модальное окно
});
```

Соответсвенно при клике на `.sendMail` можно выдернуть этот атрибут:

```
$(document).on('click', '.sendMail', function(e) { 
    var id = $(this).data('id');
});
```

Comment: получается открытие модального окна и отправка сообщения это две разные функции

Comment: В вашем примере, что в комментарии тоже две. Только ещё проблемы с логикой работы. В вашем случаи, при **каждом** клике на `openModal` вещается обработчик на `sendMail`.  Отсюда вы и получаете _"значение предыдущего клика"_.

Comment: Вы гений, спасибо большое!